# Kotlin setTargetFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I'm having problems to call a dialog callback. I am using:

```
class PerfilFragment : Fragment() {
   val fragment = MyDialog()
   fragment.setTargetFragment(**this**, 1)
   val fm = activity.fragmentManager
   fragment.show(fm, "myfragment") 
}
```

but the `setTargetFragment` method asks for a fragment and not my running `PerfilFragment`:

`Type mismatch - Required: fragment, found PerfilFragment`

Comment: use `this` not `**this**`

Comment: the ** was just to highlight where the problem is. but thanks

Comment: ok, so copy the actual code. The method from which you call etc.

Comment: check for import it should be fragment not v4.fragment

Comment: @ShivamOberoi Thank you Shivan, the dialog fragment was not in v4 version!

Answer (score 2):

Check whether both `Fragments` are from same library, because some times casting `app.Fragment` to a `v4.Fragment` might cause this kind of issues.

Comment: thank you Rajan, The Dialog was not in  v4 version, then i changed the code to and worked correctly !! 
  val fragmentTransaction = activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragment.show(fragmentTransaction, "my_constant")